# How to generate a signature with web3py like metamask does?

Tags: metamask, web3.py, signature, hash, encoding

Most ethereum apps request signatures like this

[image]

How exactly do i recreate this signature in web3 py? Is there any way i can view the data that gets sent thru metamask?

I have tried the following code without success:

```
message = encode_defunct(text='Swap 0.04 ETH Minimum: 21.64184785 ZKS To: 0xc6f8a2d663250ad86c6c58fc310238e1e5e457d6 ChainId 10 Nonce: 14 Fee: 0.0 ETHAccount Id: 75463')
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Metamask has several [api signatures](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#sign-typed-data-v4).

There is a draft of the current specification at [EIP 712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712).